# isset($_POST['reading a button']) - not working properly

Tags: php

I have a form created where user will select yes if they "have something".  I am using it inside a form which has a post action and then values get sent to .php file.  When I try to check the button using `if (isset($_POST['agentsele']))` it will not read back. I have some print statements inside to test but it never goes through.  I turned the input field from a button to a checkbox and tried it read it - it worked.  After I turned it back no go.

Here the the input field.

```
<input type="button"  value="Yes" name="agentsele" class="agentsele"/>
```

The check method.

```
if (isset($_POST['agentsele'])) {

                $emailaction = 1;//email agent and set status to - enrolled - agent emailed
                echo "agent selected";
                exit;
            }
```

I also have some JQuery that will make more input boxes slide down if the button is selected.

Thank you for your time.

UPDATED -------------------- ENTIRE FORM

```
<form name="theform" action="insert.php" method="post" >
                <div class="CheckBoxContainer">
            <input type="checkbox" value"On" name="only-thisform"/>
            <?php 
            $setError=$_GET['seterror'];

            if ($setError == 1){

                echo "<div class='errorMsg'> *Required</div>";
            }
             ?>
            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="checkbox"  value="On" name="approval" id="approval"/>
             <?php 
             $setError=$_GET['seterror'];
             if ($setError == 1){

                echo "<div class='errorMsg'> *Required</div>";
             }

             ?>
            </div><!------------------------------------END   .CheckBoxContainer ------------------------------------------->
            <br>
            <br>


<script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
</script>   
<!-- javascript on client-side -->


<div class="DropDownSelector">
<?php

$dropdown = "<select name='CompanyNames' id='CompanyNames' >";

$dropdown .= "\r\n<option  id ='' name ='' value='' class=''  ></option>";

$dropdown .= "\r\n<option  id ='other' name ='other' value='other' class='other'  >other</option>";

while($row =$FNresult->fetch()) {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option  id ='firstname' name ='first' value='{$row['CompanyNames']}'>{$row['CompanyNames']}</option>";
}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

echo $dropdown;
?>
    <div class="DropdownDiscription">Please select your insurance company.  Select other if you do not see it listed. </div>
</div> <!------------------------------------------END .DropDownSelector -------------------------------------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript">  

var dropdown = $('#CompanyNames');
//var test = $('#firstname');
//document.write(dropdown.val());

dropdown.bind('change', function(){

     if(dropdown.val() == "other"){
        $(".otherbox").slideDown(1000,function(){
           // $(this).css("border", "2px red inset")            
        });  
         $(".InputDiscriptionother").slideDown(1000,function(){
           // $(this).css("border", "2px red inset")            
        });          
    }else{
          $(".otherbox").slideUp(1000); 
           $(".InputDiscriptionother").slideUp(1000);   
    }

    $.post('backgroundScript.php', 
        { 
            'CompanyNames': dropdown.val()

        },
        function(response) {
            $('#compname').val(response.Companyname);
            //$('#phone').val(response.phone);
            //$('#policynum').val(response.policynum);
            //$('#nameofPolicyholder').val(response.policyholder);
            //$('#mailing').val(response.mailing);
            // Repeat for all of your form fields
        },
        'json'
    );

});
</script>
<br>


<!--<input type="text" class="otherbox" />
<input type="text" class="otherbox" />

<input type="text" class="otherbox"/>-->

<div class="FormBody">

    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscriptionother">Insurance Company Name: </span><div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" name="compname" id="compname" class="otherbox" ></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->

<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>

</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Insurance Phone number: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text"  name="phone" id="phone" ></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>

</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
     <div class="agensele"> Do you have an agent? <input type="button"  value="Yes" name="agentsele" class="agentsele"/></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
     <?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required only if selected</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>
     <div class="noagensele"> Do you have an agent? <input type="button"  value="No" name="noagentsele" class="noagentsele"/> </div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="agent">Agent Name: </span><div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" name="agentname"  class="agentinput" ></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->

<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="agent">Agent Phone Number: </span><div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" name="agentphone"  class="agentinput" ></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="agent">Agent's Email: </span><div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" name="agentemail"  class="agentinput" ></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="agent">Confirm Agent's Email: </span><div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" name="agentemailone"  class="agentinput" ></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<script>
$(".agentsele").click(function () {
    $(this).css({ borderStyle:"inset", cursor:"wait" });
    //dropdown.bind('change', function(){   
    $(".agentinput").slideDown(1000,function(){
    });
    $(".agent").slideDown(1000,function(){
    });
    //$(".agentsele").css("visibility", "hidden");
    //$(".agensele").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(".noagentsele").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".noagensele").css("visibility", "visible");
});
$(".noagentsele").click(function () {
    $(this).css({ borderStyle:"inset", cursor:"wait" });
    //dropdown.bind('change', function(){   
    $(".agentinput").slideUp(1000,function(){
    });
    $(".agent").slideUp(1000,function(){
    });
    $(".agentsele").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".agensele").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".noagentsele").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(".noagensele").css("visibility", "hidden");
});

</script>

<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
    <span class="InputDiscription">Name of the Policyholder: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="nameofPolicyholder" id="nameofPolicyholder"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>

</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
     <div class="InputInner"> Not the Policy Holder? <input type="checkbox"  value="On" name="notpolicyholder" class="notpolicyholder"/></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->

<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Policy Number: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name ="policynum" id="policynum" ></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Policyholder mailing address: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="mailing" id="mailing"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>

</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">City: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="city" id="city"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
    <div class="InputContainer">
    <!------------------------------------------STATE SELECTION CODE ------------------------------------------->
<?php
    function state_select ($name,$full_state,$selected = '') {

  $state_list = array("AL|Alabama","AK|Alaska","AZ|Arizona", "AR|Arkansas", "CA|California", "CO|Colorado", "CT|Connecticut", "DE|Delaware", "DC|Washington D.C.", "FL|Florida", "GA|Georgia", "HI|Hawaii", "ID|Idaho", "IL|Illinois", "IN|Indiana", "IA|Iowa", "KS|Kansas", "KY|Kentucky", "LA|Louisiana", "ME|Maine", "MD|Maryland", "MA|Massachusetts", "MI|Michigan", "MN|Minnesota", "MS|Mississippi", "MO|Missouri", "MT|Montana", "NE|Nebraska", "NV|Nevada", "NH|New Hampshire", "NJ|New Jersey", "NM|New Mexico", "NY|New York", "NC|North Carolina", "ND|North Dakota", "OH|Ohio", "OK|Oklahoma", "OR|Oregon", "PA|Pennsylvania", "RI|Rhode Island", "SC|South Carolina", "SD|South Dakota", "TN|Tennessee", "TX|Texas", "UT|Utah", "VT|Vermont", "VA|Virginia", "WA|Washington", "WV|West Virginia", "WI|Wisconsin", "WY|Wyoming");

  ?>
  <select name=<?=$name;?> id="state" onChange="submitform()"><?
    foreach ($state_list as $s) {
        $values = explode("|",$s);
        ?><option value="<?=$values[0];?>" <?
                if($selected == $values[0]) { ?>SELECTED<? }
                ?>>

                <?  if($full_state) { ?><?=$values[1];?><? } else { ?><?=$values[0];?><? } ?></option><?
    }
  ?></select><?
}
?>

<span class="InputDiscription">State: </span><div class="InputInner">
<?=state_select('state',false,'AL'); ?>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenfield" name="hiddenfield" value="">
 </div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->

<?php

 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 

?>

</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Zipcode: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Year Of Vehicle: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="YearOfVehicle" id="YearOfVehicle"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Make Of Vehicle: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="MakeOfVehicle" id="MakeOfVehicle"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Model Of Vehicle: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="ModelOfVehicle" id="ModelOfVehicle"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Vehicle Identification Number: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="Vehicleid" id="Vehicleid"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Policy Effective Date: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="Policyeffdate" id="Policyeffdate"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Policy Expiration Date: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="Policyexpdate" id="Policyexpdate"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<br>
<h2>Employee Information</h2>

<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Employee Name: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="EmployeeName" id="EmployeeName"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Employee Company Name: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="EmployeeCompanyName" id="EmployeeCompanyName"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Agency/Franchise Number (or unique indicator): </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="Agency/FranchiseNumber" id="Agency/FranchiseNumber"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="InputDiscription">Todays Date: </span><div class="InputInner"><input type="text" name="TodaysDate" id="TodaysDate" value="
<?php

$today = date("n-j-Y"); 
echo $today;
?>">
</div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
else
    //echo "<span>*</span>"; 
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<br>
<div class="CheckBoxContainer">
            <input type="checkbox" value"On" name="correct"/>The above printed name serves to identify the employee and shows intent of the employee that the above auto insurance information given is accurate.  
            <?php 
            $setError=$_GET['seterror'];

            if ($setError == 1){

                echo "<div class='errorMsg'> *Required</div>";
            }
             ?>
            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="checkbox"  value="On" name="agree" id="agree"/>The employee identified above confirms this document has been read, reviewed and understood and subsequently authorizes it as such. 
             <?php 
             $setError=$_GET['seterror'];
             if ($setError == 1){

                echo "<div class='errorMsg'> *Required</div>";
             }

             ?>
             <br>
             <br>
             <input type="checkbox"  value="On" name="understood" id="understood"/>The employee understands that if inaccurate information is discovered on the above auto insurance information table, on the employee's auto policy itself or if the auto insurance policy is cancelled for any reason, the employer will be notified. 
             <?php 
             $setError=$_GET['seterror'];
             if ($setError == 1){

                echo "<div class='errorMsg'> *Required</div>";
             }

             ?>
            </div><!------------------------------------END   .CheckBoxContainer ------------------------------------------->
            <br>
<?php 
 $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please check to make sure all required fields are filled out!');</script>";
}
?>


<input type="Submit" name="Submit" >

</div><!-------------------------------------------END .FormBody ------------------------------------------------------->
</form>
```

UPDATED-------------------

When I changed type to submit it worked but I do not want it to send me straight to the function where it inserts data.  How do I stop it from submitting.

Comment: Please post your entire form.

Comment: Also keep in mind that a button !== submit

Comment: or at least the `<form>` tag ;-)

Comment: button is nicer you can add text and it's for client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a "input" type hidden at your form and with jQuery you can add an event to you button.

Answer (score 4):

Button values are not being send with the form submit

Comment: @DavidBiga you should use a `hidden` or `submit` input, and check for *its* existence after submitting the form.

Comment: used submit but how do I stop it from submitting?

Answer (score 1):

Buttons can't contain form data, use submit instead

Comment: I did but how do I sop from submitting?

Comment: you can just add onsubmit="return false" to the form tag

Comment: but I do want to submit a form at the end when user hits submit so wouldn't that stop it?

Comment: @David Biga well yes another way would be `$('buttonselector').click(function(){return false;});`

Comment: on the insert file that it gets sent to or in form file?

Comment: at the form file it's an javascript code that prevents any submit when clicking on any given selector in your case it should look like this `$('#approval').click(function(){return false;});`

Comment: I did that then in form I checked to see if the submit button was clicked and it's not working?  the code I used to check was `if (isset($_POST['agentsele'])) {
    
    $emailaction = 1;
    echo "agent selected";
    
    exit;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

First, we could try standardizing your control.

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

---

Perhaps some clarification about buttons could help, too.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

---

"*When I changed type to submit it worked but I do not want it to send me straight to the function where it inserts data. How do I stop it from submitting.*"

I'm a little rusty with my JavaScript, but I believe you can use the `onsubmit` attribute to do something, or you can register some functions using the `onload=""` attribute of the `<form>` tag or, more commonly, the `<body>` tag. Find a good JavaScript book with a section on forms.

[http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-Activate-Guides/dp/0596805527/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1401399613&sr=1-1&keywords=javascript+the+definitive+guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805527)